# Хочу подключить библиотеку libmpg123, но в ней нет dll и lib файлов

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, библиотеки, lib

Загрузил с сайта архив с библиотекой "libmpg123", но не dll не lib, include каталогов там нет, как такие библиотеки подключаются?
Пишу в Visual Studio 2022 на Windows, язык C.

https://www.mpg123.de/download.shtml

Comment: По всей видимости, их надо сначала скомпилировать и собрать...

Comment: Или Вы что-то не то скачали. Сейчас скачал архив для win-64. Там имеются dll-файлы